# How to count the number of times a specific number is generated by sample()?

Tags: r

For example, if I roll a dice 20 times with the following code

```
set.seed(555)
dice_outcomes <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
dice_rolls <- sample(dice_outcomes, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
```

How do I count the number of times 3 was generated by the sample()?

Comment: `sum(dice_rolls == 3)`

Comment: Also  ```count(dice_rolls)``` or heck even ```table()``` there are gazillion possible solutions.